# What to do with links to GitHub gists in questions?

Tags: discussion, vote-to-close, questions

I'm looking to help Stack Overflow with post moderation more, and I came across a [question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/23525414/storing-ajax-response-into-variable-for-use-later-in-script#23525414) that simply links to a GitHub gist and doesn't provide the part of the code that is giving problems. I asked the OP to give the code that is causing the problem and an edit was made posting the problematic code. In the future, is this the correct approach or should the question be voted to close due to insufficient information to reproduce the problem?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

When you see a question linking to, rather than including, code that's necessary for understanding the problem, you should take three steps.

Comment explaining that the *relevant* code needs to be copied into the question so that it is self-contained. Emphasize that only the minimum amount of code should be included.

Edit the question to remove the link to the code; this will inhibit answers until the question is fixed, which is a small prod to the author to do the fixing.

Vote or flag to close the question. Closure prevents answers from being posted. When the question is edited, it'll be submitted to the reopen queue, where the closure can be reversed. If you're still around at the time, you can also vote to reopen yourself.

Comment: Removing the link could be problematic, i.e. lead to arguments between the original poster and editor over whether that's an OK thing to do.

Comment: Doesn't happen too often in my experience, @Cupcake, but it definitely seems to help. Handle it like any other edit conflict; don't get in an war, flag if necessary.

Answer (score 3):

The actions are not mutually exclusive.  If a post doesn't have enough information to be answerable, vote to close it.  If you would like to post a comment explaining what information is missing and/or how the author can go about improving their post to become answerable, that's great (although not required).